# If a point (lat long) lies within any polygon of a shapefile

Tags: python, shapefile, ogr, matplotlib

i checked different places to finally come up with a code which used ray casting method to check if the given lat, long was inside one of the many polygons of my shapefile. this code worked fine when i tested with a lat long inside the polygon but when when the point was not in any of polygon  it still printed TRUE

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon, Point, MultiPolygon

import shapefile as shp

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

polygon = shp.Reader("D:/New folder1/21_8_2016.shp") 

polygon = polygon.shapes()  

shpfilePoints = [ shape.points for shape in polygon ]

print shpfilePoints

polygons = shpfilePoints

for polygon in polygons:
    poly = Polygon(polygon)
    print poly


lat=15.139078
lon=120.763779

def point_in_poly(x,y,poly):

    n = len(poly)
    inside = True

    p1x,p1y = poly[0]
    for i in range(n+1):
        p2x,p2y = poly[i % n]
        if y > min(p1y,p2y):
            if y <= max(p1y,p2y):
                if x <= max(p1x,p2x):
                    if p1y != p2y:
                        xints = (y-p1y)*(p2x-p1x)/(p2y-p1y)+p1x
                    if p1x == p2x or x <= xints:
                        inside = not inside
        p1x,p1y = p2x,p2y

    return inside

print point_in_poly(lon,lat,polygon)
```

the lat lon given in the code dont lie in any of the polygon where the following lie inside of the polygon 
lat: 15.094997
lon: 120.836563

Comment: this is not a duplicate of what you shared, in that case they were just putting latitude longitude in the wrong order